# MSCharts Axis Label: not always angled correctly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mschart

I'm formatting MSCHARTS.  I can get the AXIS label to appear on 45 degree angle, SOMETIMES.  Is there a way to force it to ALWAYS be 45 degrees?

Sometimes it's correct like this:
[image]

But, sometimes it's like this (could be a function of the number of columns?):
[image]

code-behind:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = True
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = DataVisualization.Charting.LabelAutoFitStyles.LabelsAngleStep45
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = True
```

Comment: Have you tried this one art1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 45;

Comment: BWS ~ Yes.As per Hans answer I have tested it. It's working. Please try it.

Comment: @HansDerks -- (and @mit) --- that seems to have done it!! if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this one
 art1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 45;